# How to use write command to send message to user in debian stretch

Tags: debian, tty, write

`who` command show that *xyz* user is on tty2.

```
$ who
xyz tty2         2018-06-22 08:18 (:0)
```

I trying send message to *xyz* using `write xyz` command. But it does not shows on terminal.

When I run `tty` command on xyz user terminal.

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/1
```

but `write` says user is not logged in on pts/1

```
$ write xyz pts/1
write: xyz is not logged in on pts/1
```

According to this [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/6jdyzy/cant_open_text_terminal_with_ctrlaltf1_any_longer/djf37ez), in *Debian Stretch* Login session is usually on tty2.

So I think message is being sent to xyz user terminal, but since login session is open on that tty. It is not being displayed.

How can write message to opened terminal of xyz on debian stretch.

Comment: `echo "message" > /dev/pts/1` (Reference: [*How to send a message to a specific pts?*](https://serverfault.com/a/282865/547511))

Answer (score 3):

write uses utmp to determine who is logged in. an x-terminal does not count as a log-in  only a connection that was mediated by /bin/login (or similar)

so `ssh` into localhost, get the new `tty` and try write again.

Comment: Already very helpful but I think it would be more helpful if you could supply any source.